# SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER: Object is currently in trigger CaseTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have a process builder on Email Message object, from this process builder i am updating case 'last_activity_date__c' with system .now() when a email is sent from case related list "send Email". 
I have a trigger on case which send an email when case is closed,

Now I am getting SELF_REFERENCE_ERROR. 
I tried changing the method causing error calling in trigger from before update to after update then I am getting 101 soql.

Can anyone have an idea how to solve this

Error:

### > Error:Apex trigger CaseTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CaseTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “UpdateCaseFromRelatedEmail” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER: Object (id = 50022000002xkHk) is currently in trigger CaseTrigger, therefore it cannot recursively update itself. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 671972233-138629 (1525238937): []: Class.UOP_CaseHandler.autoPopulateTimeStampAndSendEmail: line 535, column 1

Method i am Getting error: parameters from trigger are trigger.new and trigger.oldmap

```
public void autoPopulateTimeStampAndSendEmail(List<Case> caseList, Map<Id, Case> mapOfOldCases)
{
    Map<Id,String> mapOfCaseDesc = new Map<Id,String>();
    recordType();
    Set<Id> setOfCaseIDs = new Set<Id>();
    List<Id> toAddressList = new List<Id>();


    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messageList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messageListChildCase  = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    if(HelperClass.firstRun )
    {

        List<EmailTemplate> closedCaseTemplate =  [Select Id,Body,Subject From EmailTemplate Where IsActive = true and 
                                                DeveloperName =: CASE_CLOSED  Limit 1];


        List<EmailTemplate> resassignmentTemplate = [Select Id,Body,Subject From EmailTemplate Where IsActive = true and 
                                                    DeveloperName =: CASE_ASSIGNMENT  Limit 1]; 

        List<EmailTemplate> childCaseTemplate = [Select Id,Body,Subject From EmailTemplate Where IsActive = true and 
                                                    DeveloperName =: CASE_ASSIGNMENT_CHILDCASE Limit 1]; 

        List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWideAddressList = [Select id, Address, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where 
                                                        DisplayName  =: Label.UOP_GenericEmailBoxName];

        for(Case caseObj : caseList)
        {
            if(caseObj.RecordTypeId == serviceRequesRecordExernalTypeId ||
                    caseObj.RecordTypeId ==  serviceRequesRecordExernalReadOnlyTypeId)
            {                    
                 String newDescriptionUpdate; 
                 String htmlDescription = '';
                 String htmlUserTimeStamp = '';

                if((caseObj.Origin == 'Web' || caseObj.Origin == 'Email'||caseObj.Origin =='Phone call') && 
                    caseObj.RecordTypeId == serviceRequesRecordExernalTypeId)
                {

                    if(caseObj.External_Discussion__c != null)
                    {
                        String userTimeStamp = '';

                        if(!loggedInUserList.isEmpty())
                        {
                            userTimeStamp += loggedInUserList[0].FirstName+'  '+loggedInUserList[0].LastName+ '  '+ timeStamp + '\r\n';
                            userTimeStamp += '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
                            htmlUserTimeStamp += loggedInUserList[0].FirstName+'  '+loggedInUserList[0].LastName+ '  '+ timeStamp + '<br/>';
                            htmlUserTimeStamp += '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
                        }

                        if(caseObj.Origin == 'Web' &&  !caseObj.IsNotManual__c)
                        {
                            newDescriptionUpdate = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '\r\n'+ userTimeStamp;
                            htmlDescription  = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '<br/>'+ htmlUserTimeStamp;
                            System.debug('Enter into loop1');
                        }
                        else if(caseObj.Origin == 'Phone call' &&  !caseObj.IsNotManual__c)
                        {
                            newDescriptionUpdate = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '\r\n'+ userTimeStamp;
                            htmlDescription  = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '<br/>'+ htmlUserTimeStamp;
                            System.debug('Enter into loop2');
                        }
                        else if(caseObj.Origin == 'Email' && !caseObj.IsNotManual__c)
                        {
                            caseObj.IsCaseEdited__c = true;
                            newDescriptionUpdate = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '\r\n' +userTimeStamp;
                            htmlDescription  = caseObj.External_Discussion__c + '<br/>'+ htmlUserTimeStamp;
                            System.debug('Enter into loop3');
                        }


                        if(newDescriptionUpdate != null && newDescriptionUpdate != '')
                        {
                            caseObj.External_Discussion__c = null;
                            if(caseObj.Description == null)
                            {
                                caseObj.Description = '';
                            }
                             htmlDescription = htmlDescription  +'<br/>'+caseObj.Description;
                            caseObj.Description = newDescriptionUpdate  + '\r\n' +caseObj.Description;
                           System.debug('enetr update@@@@@@');
                            if(!caseObj.Depress_Customer_Notification__c && caseObj.First_Customer_Contact_date__c == null)
                            {
                                caseObj.First_Customer_Contact_date__c = System.Now();
                                caseObj.Last_Customer_Contact_Date__c = System.Now();
                            }
                            else if(!caseObj.Depress_Customer_Notification__c && caseObj.First_Customer_Contact_date__c != null)
                            {
                                caseObj.Last_Customer_Contact_Date__c = System.Now();
                            }
                        }  
                      }
                       if(caseObj!=null && mapOfOldCases!=null) 
                       {
                    if(mapOfOldCases.get(caseObj.Id).ParentId == null && caseObj.ParentId != null)
                    {
                        caseObj.IsChildCase__c = true; //to make the IsChildCase__c  as true for the child cases to send the different notifications to customer
                    }
                   }

                    //To send different notification to customers for the child case creations
                    if(!caseObj.Depress_Customer_Notification__c && caseObj.IsChildCase__c)
                    {
                        toAddressList.add(caseObj.ContactID);
                        if(htmlDescription != '' && htmlDescription != null)
                        {
                            mapOfCaseDesc.put(caseObj.Id, htmlDescription  );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             mapOfCaseDesc.put(caseObj.Id, caseObj.Description);   
                        }
                        if(caseObj.contactId != null)
                        {
                            messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                            message.toAddresses = toAddressList;
                            message.setWhatId(caseObj.id);

                            if(!closedCaseTemplate.isEmpty())
                            {
                                message.setTemplateId(childCaseTemplate[0].Id);
                            }

                            message.setTargetObjectId(caseObj.contactId);
                            if(!orgWideAddressList.isempty())
                            {
                                message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideAddressList[0].Id);
                            }
                            message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                            messageListChildCase.add(message);
                            caseObj.last=system.now();
                        } 

                    }
                    caseObj.IsChildCase__c = false;  
                }
                else if(caseObj!=null && mapOfOldCases!=null && caseObj.Origin == 'Manual' &&  (caseObj.RecordTypeId == serviceRequesRecordExernalTypeId || caseObj.RecordTypeId == serviceRequesRecordExernalReadOnlyTypeId ))
                {
                    if(mapOfOldCases.get(caseObj.Id).Origin == null && caseObj.Origin == 'Manual')
                    {
                        caseObj.OwnerId = caseObj.CreatedById;
                        Database.DMLOptions options = new Database.DMLOptions();
                        options.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
                        if(!loggedInUserList.isEmpty())
                        {
                            caseObj.OwnerId = loggedInUserList[0].Id;
                        }
                        caseObj.setOptions(options);
                    }


                    if((caseObj.External_Discussion__c != null || caseObj.External_Discussion__c != '') && 
                        mapOfOldCases.get(caseObj.Id).External_Discussion__c != caseObj.External_Discussion__c )
                    {
                        String newDescriptionUpdate1 = populateDescriptionTimeStampManual(caseObj.External_Discussion__c );
                        String appendDescription = caseObj.Description +'\r\n'+newDescriptionUpdate1 ;
                        caseObj.Description = appendDescription;
                        caseObj.External_Discussion__c = null;
                    }
                }

               //whenever a case is re-opened,the Re_opened__c checkbox is marked as true. Used for reporting purpose
               if(caseObj!=null && mapOfOldCases!=null) 
                       {
                if(mapOfOldCases.get(caseObj.Id).Status == 'Closed' && caseObj.Status == 'Open')
                {
                    caseObj.Re_opened__c = true;
                    caseObj.UOP_Date_Closed__c = null;
                }
                 }
                 //To send notification to customer for the closed cases    
                if(caseObj!=null && mapOfOldCases!=null) 
                       {
                if(caseObj.Origin != 'Manual' && !caseObj.Depress_Customer_Notification__c && !(mapOfOldCases.get(caseObj.Id).Status == 'Closed' && caseObj.Status == 'Closed') 
                    && caseObj.Status == 'Closed')
                {
                    caseObj.UOP_Date_Closed__c = Date.Today();
                    toAddressList.add(caseObj.ContactID);

                    if(caseObj.contactId != null)
                    {
                        messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        message.toAddresses = toAddressList;
                        message.setWhatId(caseObj.id);
                        if(!closedCaseTemplate.isEmpty())
                        {
                            message.setTemplateId(closedCaseTemplate[0].Id);
                        }
                        message.setTargetObjectId(caseObj.contactId);
                        if(!orgWideAddressList.isempty())
                        {
                            message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideAddressList[0].Id);
                        }
                        message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                        messageList.add(message);
                    } 
                }
                }


        }

    }



    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    if(!messageListChildCase.isEmpty())
    {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        Messaging.sendEmail(messageListChildCase);
        Database.rollback(sp); 

        for (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email : messageListChildCase) 
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            emailToSend.setToAddresses(email.getToAddresses());
            emailToSend.setWhatId(email.whatId);
            emailToSend.setTargetObjectId(email.getTargetObjectId());
            String descriptionBody = mapOfCaseDesc.get(email.whatId);

            if(descriptionBody == null)
            {
                descriptionBody = '';
            }

            emailToSend.setHTMLBody(email.getHTMLBody().replace('{DescriptionFromApex}', descriptionBody ));
            emailToSend.setSubject(email.getSubject());
            if(!orgWideAddressList.isempty())
            {
                emailToSend.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideAddressList[0].Id);
            }
            emailToSend.setSaveAsActivity(true);
            lstMsgsToSend.add(emailToSend);
        }
    }

    if(!lstMsgsToSend .isEmpty())
    {
        Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgsToSend );
    }

    if(!messageList.isEmpty())
    {
        Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);
    }
        HelperClass.firstRun = false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: We would need to see the trigger coffee to help you.

Comment: Following is method in Line 535 i am getting the Error. line 535 i have this  Messaging.sendEmail(messageList);,    i have a process builder on email message to update case custom field with system.now()

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you probably need to do some sort of recursion checking in your trigger, or you need to do some "rising edge" trigger logic (i.e. check if a value meets your criteria and has changed).

Comment: i have added my code

Comment: Suri - way too much of a code dump here; see [ask] and reduce to the size of your post (using [edit]) to get the most help